# Horizontally scrolling text in a JPanel or JTextField (like news bar in TV)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

Can anybody give me some advice on how can I do that? I found some code on the internet but I don't know how to use it how to add it to my code and use it since that code creates a frame on its own.

How can I assign a `JLabel` to this code?

Here is the code (I want to use this for a label I have on a frame I created):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
 
public class JScrollingText extends JLabel {
 
    private int speed;
 
    private int period;
 
    private int offset;
 
    private int x;
 
    public JScrollingText(String text) {
        this(text, 1);
    }
 
    public JScrollingText(String text, int speed) {
        this(text, speed, 100);
    }
 
    public JScrollingText(String text, int speed, int period) {
        this(text, speed, period, 0);
    }
 
    public JScrollingText(String text, int speed, int period, int offset) {
        super(text);
        this.speed = speed;
        this.period = period;
        this.offset = offset;
    }
 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (isOpaque()) {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        g.setColor(getForeground());
 
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        Insets insets = getInsets();
 
        int width = getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
        int height = getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
 
        int textWidth = fm.stringWidth(getText());
        if (width < textWidth) {
            width = textWidth + offset;
        }
        x %= width;
 
        int textX = insets.left + x;
        int textY = insets.top + (height - fm.getHeight()) / 2  + fm.getAscent();
 
        g.drawString(getText(), textX, textY);
        g.drawString(getText(), textX + (speed > 0 ? -width : width), textY);
    }
 
    public void start() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                x += speed;
                repaint();
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, period);
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quitter");
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(quit);
        JScrollingText scrollingText1 = new JScrollingText("Barre des tâches... Pressez le bouton Quitter", -3);
        scrollingText1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        scrollingText1.start();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollingText1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JScrollingText scrollingText2 = new JScrollingText("Barre des tâches... Pressez le bouton Quitter");
        scrollingText2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        scrollingText2.start();
        scrollingText2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        scrollingText2.setOpaque(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollingText2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't extend a JLabel. A JLabel already has custom painting code. Extend either a JComponent or JPanel to add your custom painting code. 2) Don't use an AWT Timer for animation. All Swing components should be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. So you should be using the [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for animation. 3) Check out the [Marquee Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/) for one approach.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenu aux les Stacks.

The key lines are

```
       frame.getContentPane().add(scrollingText1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

       frame.getContentPane().add(scrollingText2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

You will have to do a similar `.add` to an appropriate container or component in your code.

You will probably have to create an instance of `JScrollPane` or some kind of Pane, add that to your GUI, and add the `ScrollingText(s)` to that.

Also, I think it better to not use the J initial for the scrolling text class.  That will help you (and other coders?) avoid thinking it is part of the Java libraries.  Call the class ScrollingText or RKScrollingText or similar.